# Revert File not in a workspace in perforce

Tags: perforce, workspace

I am trying to delete an old user from our perforce installation.  A previous admin had deleted all their active workspaces / clients so we should be able to now delete the user, however when i run

```
p4 user -f -d auser
User auser has file(s) open on 1 client(s) and can't be deleted.
```

However auser no longer has any associated clients, and if I filter the pending changelist view in P4V it shows the user as having one file checked out in the default changelist but no client is specified.  Even if I log in as the user I dont seem to be able to revert or do anything with the file.  Any hints how I might solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.

A bit weird but this is what I did.  I got the details of the default changelist that contained the file.  It had the workspace name which was the name of a machine.  I logged into the machine and then into perforce as the user.  At this point I could see the pending changelist and revert the file.  Now I can delete the user.

How did this happen?

I think what must of happened was a confusion of clients.  A while back I changed the owner of quite a few clients on that machine (its the build server) and some of these clients must have had open files for the old user.  This is the only explanation I can come up with.

Answer (score 6):

While both of these commands returned nothing:

```
$ p4 clients -u <USER>

$ p4 changes -s pending -u <USER>
```

This command showed me which file was open:

```
$ p4 opened -u <USER>
//depot/path/to/file#1 - edit default change (text) by <USER>@<CLIENT>
```

This command doesn't work:

```
$ p4 -u <USER> -H <CLIENT> revert -k //depot/path/to/file
//depot/path/to/file#1 - belongs to user <USER>, not reverted
```

Deleting the client does:

```
$ p4 client -o <CLIENT> > <CLIENT>.txt
$ p4 client -d -f <CLIENT>
$ p4 opened -u <USER>
File(s) not opened anywhere.
```

FTW! \o/

If you need to, you can then recreate the client with:

```
$ p4 client
```

Then read in the `<CLIENT>.txt` file you created with the output of `p4 client -o <CLIENT>` and save it.

More here:
http://answers.perforce.com/articles/KB_Article/Reverting-Another-User-s-Files